# UITextChecker: Memory Issue With Learning Thousands Of Words

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, csv

I am trying to parse a medical dictionary (.csv file) and then learn all those words through the `UITextChecker`: learnword method so that the spellchecker approves those medical terms as valid words.

I am calling this method in another thread but the amount of words in the csv file is around 50K.

```
- (void)parseMyCSVFile{

for (int i = 1; i < [csvContent count]; i++) {
    NSString *learntWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[csvContent objectAtIndex:i]];

    NSString *s = learntWord;
    NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ()\n\""];
    s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];


    if ([UITextChecker hasLearnedWord:s]){

        NSLog(@"skipped");

    }
    else
    {
        [UITextChecker learnWord:s]; // Memory Issue Here
        NSLog(@"learning");
    }

    HUD.detailsLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i of %i",i,[csvContent count]];
}

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(bgWorkEnded) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

}
```

I have applied Instruments Time Profiler and found out that the problem lies in the line where I am learning word inside the loop.

The app tries to load the dictionary till 5000 words (approx) and then crashes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You're definitely stress testing UITextChecker in ways Apple's QA group probably never expected.  You're 1) using it in a background thread instead of the main (UI) thread and 2) you're trying to add thousands of words at a time. If you don't get a decent response from somebody else, I'd recommend packaging up as much code as you can disclose (which demonstrates the problem) and file a bug at [http://bugreporter.apple.com](http://bugreporter.apple.com) sending them that code to try it out themselves.

Comment: Use a @autoreleasepool

Comment: You're creating 2 NSStrings and an NSCharacterSet for every iteration. Profile your app to see if that's significant.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Thanks for your answer. I have tried to run the app in the main thread as well but it crashed as well. Although it crashed a bit later almost after 10K words. Plus I have filed a bug at bugreporter.apple.com. Let's see when Apple reply to my problem :)

Comment: @j_mcnally I actually tried it but not much use.

Comment: @jcm I have Profiled my app but the most labor intensive work is done on [UITextChecker learnWord:s] not with the NSStrings or NSCharacterSet.

Comment: I realize this is and old question, but I've seen performance slow downs simply NSLogging too much. Shouldn't crash though. @n.by.n did you find any way to actually have learned words show up as suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You must not call UIKit class methods on a background thread--this **will** result in crashes.  Also, you **must** create an autorelease pool inside your method so that you do not leak any objects. Since UITextChecker must be used on the main thread, I'd recommend only adding a few words at a time, then returning to the run loop so that you don't stall the app. Display a spinner to the user during this process so they know what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

just change the value of i = 0. This will help you.
For example:

```
for (i=0; i<[csvContent count]; i++)
```